# Samsung Note 3 cannot detect finger touch

Tags: touchscreen, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I'm using the Galaxy Note 3, and suddenly it cannot detect my finger touch! It works normally with the S Pen. I tried factory resetting, turning it off and on, and taking out the battery but it still behaves the same!

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem to me. Why don't you exchange it especially when it's under warranty.